# How to change the color of each field in text-shelf of tableau and add legends for the colors -Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am in the process of converting few of my `ssrs` reports into `tableau`. I created a tabular model `worksheet` which shows Comparison of `budget & actual amount` in `region, district , year` wise. I have added `region, district` in `row shelf` and `budget & actual` amounts in `text shelf.`

[image]

Now I need to show `Budget & actual` amounts in different color.  Also I need to add a `legend` for each text colors. Please help how to do this tableau.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the `Measure Values` measure in the `Text` card instead. This will allow you to use the `Measure Names` dimension in the `Color` card.

For example:

[image]

You will need to filter on `Measure Names` to make sure you only include those two measures.

Also, I added `Measure Names` to the `Rows` section, but unchecked `Show Header` so that the numbers are vertically stacked.